# List and HashMap group

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I just had an issue that I couldn't solve and I would like your opinion.
I have reached at a stage after reading some input files where I have an Array List of objects which includes a number and a color and from the other side I have a HashMap which includes these numbers with names associated.What I want to do is compare the numbers in these two collections and in the end group them by name.That's what I have at the moment and the output I want to succeed.

**INPUT**

HashMap  names

1-Bill
2–John
3-Jason
4-Jack
5-Michael
6-Chris

ArrayList numbers

**2**-red
**3**-yellow
**1**-green
**2**-pink
**2**-gold
**1**-pink
**4**-brown

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
  Bill [ green  , pink ]
  John[ red , pink , gold ]
  Jason[ blue , red ]
  Jack [ brown ]
```

I have written this code:

```
public Map<String,String> getAllDetails(){
        HashMap<String , String> theEnd =new HashMap<String ,String>(); 

            for (Numbers t : numbers ) {
                  String plate = t.getNumber();
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : names.entrySet()) {
                  String key = entry.getKey();
                       if(plate.equals(key)) {
                          theEnd.put( t.getName() ,entry.getValue());     
                       }
                }       
            }
        return theEnd;
}
```

And the result I get is Pink = Bill , gold = John  , red = Jason ,brown=Jack

So for each color I get a name instead of getting all the colors for each name.
What can I do to get all the colors and group them by name??

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It looks like you're doing it backwards. Get the person, then iterate over the numbers pulling the ones that match the associated number of the person. BTW, your example data and desired outputs don't seem to match.

Comment: Your input ArrayList of `Numbers` is not in terms with your desired output. can you update that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a `Map<String,String[]>` or `Map<String,ArrayList<String>>` and for each name (`String`) you create a list (`ArrayList<String> or String[]`) and you add the colors to the created list.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has logically problem. Do change like

1. Convert map value as List like  `HashMap<String , List<String>> theEnd =new HashMap<String ,List<String>>`
2. First loop should be on `names`, than on `numbers`. You need to check for each person has key i.e.`1` significant how may color. (numbers).
3. Add inner number object values into `List<String>`
4. After complete looping, do looping on `theEnd` map and desplay values.

Finally `theEnd` has value each member respectively `colors`.

Comment: I think this is which I make the mistake how can I check for each name how many colors has.Because with the condition if which I use  if(plate.equals(key)) cannot get back how many colors each name has.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should try to find names for your classes/variables/methods that means something for the domain at hand. For instance `theEnd` is not really explicit. Technically, the method `getAllDetails` does a join of 2 collections on the "plate number" key.

Anyway, here is a commented solution to your problem :

As I understand, you have some class Number that contains a "plate" number and a color. Depending on what you intend to do with this bean class, you should complete with `equals` and `hashcode` methods.

```
    public class Number {
        String plate;
        String color;

        public Number(String plate, String color) {
            this.plate = plate;
            this.color = color;
        }
        public String getPlate() {
            return plate;
        }
        public String getColor() {
            return color;
        }
    }
```

I suppose `numbers` and `names` are collections declared in global scope for `getAllDetails`.

```
    List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, String> names = new HashMap<>();
```

The result of `getAllDEtails` is a `Map` whose key is a `String` that holds the name, and the value is a `Set` of `String` to hold the colors.

```
    public static Map<String, Set<String>> getAllDetails()
    {
        // No duplicate of color for each name => use a Set
        Map<String , Set<String>> theEnd = new HashMap<>(); 

        for (Number t : numbers) {
            String plate = t.getPlate();

            // find name associated with plate
            String name = names.get(plate);

            if (name != null) {
                // find if the corresponding name exists in result map 
                Set<String> colors = theEnd.get(name);

                // If the name is not already there create the Set and put the entry
                if (colors == null) {
                    colors = new HashSet<>();
                    theEnd.put(name, colors);
                }
                // Add the color to the Set
                colors.add(t.getColor());
            }
        }
        return theEnd;
    }
```

And you can test this with :

```
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        numbers.add(new Number("2", "red"));
        numbers.add(new Number("3", "blue"));
        numbers.add(new Number("2", "gold"));
        numbers.add(new Number("1000", "black"));

        names.put("2",  "Joe");
        names.put("3",  "Mickael");
        System.out.println(getAllDetails());
    }
```

It gives : `{Joe=[red, gold], Mickael=[blue]}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm changing your map and list names just to make it easier to read, although your `Numbers` class is little clueless because you call the property as name but you actually mean a color name, I'm not changing that now but I suggest you change that as well :)

If you're on JDK7 or above, you can use diamond operator skipping type definition on right hand side, something like this

```
    Map<String,String> namesMap = new HashMap<>();
    List<Numbers> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
```

coming to your getAllDetails(), the problem with your code is that your Map values are of type `String` but you actually want to capture a list of color strings, so change your `theEnd` map like below.

```
  Map<String , List<String>> theEnd =new HashMap<>();

   /* As you want a map( name, list(colors) ), start iterating on map 
      so that it's easy to read your logic. Also iterate on keySet
      of numbers rather than on entries */    

      for(String num : namesMap.keySet()){
          // get the person name for a number
          String name = namesMap.get(num);
          for(Numbers number : numbers){
              // get the number from each Numbers object
              String plate = number.getNumber();
              if(plate.equals(num)){
                  // if numbers match get the colorsList by name
                  List<String> colorList = theEnd.get(name);
                  /*first time you find a number, colorsList
                    will be null, so initialize it to empty list*/
                  if( colorList == null) {
                      colorList = new ArrayList<String>();
                  }
                  colorList.add(number.getName());
                  /* after adding your color to colorsList,
                     update the entry in map again */ 
                  theEnd.put(name, colorList);
              }
          }

      }
      // Finally print your values
      for(String person : theEnd.keySet()){
         System.out.println(person+"->"+theEnd.get(person));
      }
```

With this, for your input, I got the following output

```
Bill->[green, pink]
John->[red, pink, gold]
Jason->[yellow]
Jack->[brown]
```